# MATLAB error in "imhist" even though image processing toolbox is installed

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a color enriched image, which I converted to gray scale in MATLAB. But when I want to display the histogram of the gray image, the error message it outputs is

> Undefined function or variable '`imhist`'.

Interestingly, `imread()` and `imshow()` command works well though. I checked if the image processing toolbox is installed and it looks like yes.

```
>> license('test', 'image_toolbox')

ans = 
     1
```

Also see attached screenshot of toolboxes installed in the [attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vnxi3.jpg).

The code I used is:

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

test_image = imread('fractals.jpg');
whos;

test_image(1,1,:);
test_image(200,262,:);
figure, imshow(test_image);
size(test_image)

test_image_gray = rgb2gray(test_image);
figure, imshow(test_image_gray)

%figure, imhist(test_image)
imhist(test_image_gray)
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: `license('test', 'image_toolbox')` does not test to see if the license is installed, it checks to see if a license is *available* to check out, and does not indicate whether or not it's installed (use [`ver`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ver.html) to do this). Your screenshot of installed toolboxes does not include the Image Processing toolbox, so you'll need to install it. `imread` and `imshow` are not part of the Image Processing toolbox, so their functioning is not a helpful diagnostic here.

Comment: Thank you.  The ver command proved that I do not have the toolbox. Now my question is, Is it possible to install image processing toolbox standalone after installing Matlab, since I already have MatLab installed on my laptop.

Comment: @ rayreng, I will need other utilities from image processing toolbox for sure. So, I need to install it, but could not figure it out how, yet.

Comment: @ rayreng, I will need other utilities from image processing toolbox for sure. So, I need to install it, but could not figure it out how, yet.

Comment: Thank you guys, I fixed it after rerunning the instillation file and selecting the desired toolboxes.